# Changing Mysql functions to Mysqli breaks the script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this script that deletes a certain picture from the website. It's written with mysql functions so i wanted to update it to mysqli but doing so makes the script stop working. No die message from the script are shown no php errors and adding error_reporting(E_ALL); doesn't show any errors either.

Original script:

```
    if(isset($_POST['F3Verwijderen']))
    try 
    {                           
        //delete the file
        $sql = "SELECT PandFoto3 FROM tblpand WHERE `PK_Pand` = '".$pandid."'";

        $con = mysql_connect('WEBSITE.mysql', 'WEBSITE', 'PASS');
        if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("WEBSITE");
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                     
            if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$row['PandFoto3'])) {
                unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$row['PandFoto3']);
            } else {
            echo $row['PandFoto3'];
            }
        }
        //delete the path url from the database field
        mysql_query("UPDATE tblpand SET PandFoto3 = NULL WHERE `PK_Pand` = '".$pandid."'");
        mysql_close($con);          


        header('Location: ../admin/pand-aanpassen.php?id='.$pandid);
    }
```

Updated to mysqli:

```
try 
    {                           
        //delete the file
        $sql = "SELECT PandFoto3 FROM tblpand WHERE `PK_Pand` = '".$pandid."'";

        $con = mysqli_connect('WEBSITE.mysql', 'WEBSITE', 'PASS');
        if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
        }
        mysqli_select_db("WEBSITE");
        $result = mysqli_query($sql, $con);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {                        
            if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$row['PandFoto3'])) {
                unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$row['PandFoto3']);
            } else {
            echo $row['PandFoto3'];
            }
        }
        //delete the path url from the database field
        mysqli_query("UPDATE tblpand SET PandFoto3 = NULL WHERE `PK_Pand` = '".$pandid."'");
        mysqli_close($con);         


        header('Location: ../admin/pand-aanpassen.php?id='.$pandid);
    }
```

Comment: reverse these `($sql, $con)` - Horse first, then the wagon ;-) you're also not doing anything with `mysqli_query("UPDATE`

Comment: I changed that but same result (despite veing wagon first, then the horse it did work with old mysql).

Comment: and you're not connecting to your db

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

> *"no php errors and adding error_reporting(E_ALL); doesn't show any errors either."*

- That's because it isn't a PHP issue, it's a MySQL issue.

  - Those are two different animals altogether.

As I said in commments, you need to switch these variables `($sql, $con)` around `($con, $sql)`.

Then this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('WEBSITE.mysql', 'WEBSITE', 'PASS');
```

Just use the 4th parameter instead of `mysqli_select_db("WEBSITE");` where you didn't pass the connection variable to.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('WEBSITE.mysql', 'WEBSITE', 'PASS', 'WEBSITE');
```

The syntax is:

- host
- username
- password (if any)
- database

You also could have done `mysqli_select_db($con, "WEBSITE");`

Sidenote: In `mysql_` *(see footnotes)*, the connection comes last, unlike in `mysqli_` which comes first.

Do the same for your UPDATE and pass the connection parameter first.

```
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE...
```

Sidenote: To verify that the update truly was successful, use `affected_rows()`

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php.

Another thing, `mysqli_error()` requires a connection to it `mysqli_error($con)` and check for errors for your queries.

I.e.:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Sidenote:

You're using `try()` but no `catch()`. Either remove it, or consult the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Example #4 pulled from the manual:

```
<?php
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    return 1/$x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} finally {
    echo "First finally.\n";
}

try {
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
} finally {
    echo "Second finally.\n";
}

// Continue execution
echo "Hello World\n";
?>
```

---

Final notes:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Footnotes: (MySQL and MySQLi comparison)

In regards to `mysql_query()`:

> mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ]

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

For `mysqli_query()`:

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php